# Can you tell kubernetes to start one pod before another?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Can I add some config so that my daemon pods start before other pods can be scheduled or nodes are designated as ready?

Adding post edit:

These are 2 different pods altogether, the daemonset is a downstream dependency to any pods that might get scheduled on the host.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such a thing as [Pod hierarchy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/) in Kubernetes between multiple separate types of pods. Meaning belonging to different Deployments, Statefulsets, Daemonsets, etc.  In other words, there is no notion of a master pod and children pods. If you like to create your custom hierarchy you can build your own tooling around, for example waiting for the status of all pods in a DaemonSet to start or create a new Pod or Kubernetes workload resource.

The closest in terms of pod dependency in K8s is [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

As per the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees):

> For a StatefulSet with N replicas, when Pods are being deployed, they are created sequentially, in order from {0..N-1}.

Comment: Is there a node readiness concept ? similar to a pod-readiness probe ?

Comment: Yes, but it's not something that you can modify. It's used internally within Kubernetes. More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#manual-node-administration) You can actually configure [eviction thresholds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) what does this have to do with pod start dependency?

Comment: I was hoping that orchestrate a way so that my node could be `schedulable` only after my daemon sets are running.

Comment: Oh you can do that with [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)

Comment: @Rico How exactly would taints and tolerations help with ensuring the DaemonSet pods are running before the other Pods are scheduled/started?

Comment: @FabianSchmied you probably have to write a custom scheduler. i.e: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/21/writing-crl-scheduler/